# Dynamic xpath using anchor tag

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Can any please help me in finding the dynamic xapth?
I have tried with,

```
@FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(@href,’friend#/friends/myfriends/friendsrequest’)]")
public WebElement lnk_FrndsSeeAll;
```

Here is the HTMl code,

```html
<a class="pull-right see" href="friend#/friends/myfriends/friendsrequest">See all</a>
```

Comment: It's working fine with below code
@FindBy(xpath="//a[startswith(@href,'friend#/friends/myfriends/friendsrequest')]")
public WebElement lnk_FrndsSeeAll;

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: If you found the answer, post it as an answer and accept it so that the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can following xpath, which I'm taking using text in the anchor tag

```
//a[contains(text(),'See all')]
```

`See all` should be constant always, then only above xpath will work

Comment: It's working fine with this code, @FindBy(xpath="//a[startswith(@href,'friend#/friends/myfriends/friendsrequest')]‌​‌​") 
Actually there are two see all link, so i used href.

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine with beloew code,
@FindBy(xpath="//a[startswith(@href,'friend#/friends/myfriends/friendsrequest')]‌​‌​")

```html
<a class="pull-right see" href="friend#/friends/myfriends/friendsrequest">See all</a>
```

```html
<a class="pull-right see" href="friend#/friends/myfriends/friendsrequest">See all</a>
```